# UITableView crashes with "EXC_BREAKPOINT"

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, crashlytics

I just release a new version of my mobile application, everything seems to go pretty well but I'm facing a weird crash on one of my tableviews.
This crash occurs on different devices (iPhone 7, iPhone 5s, etc) and with different iOS versions (iOS 10, iOS 11, etc).
I tried to spot some memory leaks or zombies with no luck. This is a crash report I received from Crashlytics (this bug affects 0.44% of my users).

```
#0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  App                            0x1024d8d40 specialized ResultsViewController.tableView(UITableView, cellForRowAt : IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell (ResultsViewController.swift)
1  App                            0x1024d06e4 @objc ResultsViewController.tableView(UITableView, cellForRowAt : IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell (ResultsViewController.swift)
2  UIKit                          0x18dbcd474 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 668
3  UIKit                          0x18dbcd9d8 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 80
4  UIKit                          0x18dbad670 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2140
5  UIKit                          0x18d968f10 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 140
6  UIKit                          0x18d895000 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1256
7  QuartzCore                     0x1884650b4 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 184
8  QuartzCore                     0x188469194 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 332
9  QuartzCore                     0x1883d7f24 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 336
10 QuartzCore                     0x1883fe340 CA::Transaction::commit() + 540
11 QuartzCore                     0x1883ff180 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 92
12 CoreFoundation                 0x18442f8b8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
13 CoreFoundation                 0x18442d270 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 412
14 CoreFoundation                 0x18442d82c __CFRunLoopRun + 1292
15 CoreFoundation                 0x18434e2d8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
16 GraphicsServices               0x1861dff84 GSEventRunModal + 100
17 UIKit                          0x18d8fb880 UIApplicationMain + 208
18 App                            0x1024614e4 main (AppDelegate.swift:15)
19 libdyld.dylib                  0x183e7256c start + 4
```

Only one report has this additional line:

```
1  App                        0xbca7c specialized ResultsViewController.tableView(UITableView, cellForRowAt : IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell (ResultsViewController.swift:587)
```

Here my `cellForRowAt` method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if isResultsEmpty && indexPath.section == itinerariesIndex {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ShimmerCell", for: indexPath) as! ShimmerCell
        if bookmark != nil {
            cell.setup(true) // start shimmering
        }
        return cell
    }

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "\(cellIdentifier)\(cellTypeIdentifier)Cell", for: indexPath) as! RoundTripCell
    cell.delegate = self
    let itinerary: Itinerary = self.dataSource[indexPath.section].getSectionItineraries()[indexPath.row] // line 587
    if let _ = bookmark, indexPath.section == bookmarksIndex {
        cell.setup(true, founded: self.founded) // start animation
    } else {
        cell.setup(false, founded: false) // stop animation
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let depTrip = itinerary.getTrips()[0]

        cell.depOtaLogo.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: (depTrip.carrierMediumLogo)), placeholderImage: nil)
        cell.depTimeLabel.text = depTrip.getDepartureArrivalTime()
        cell.depDelay.text = depTrip.getDelayString()
        cell.depIataLabel.text = depTrip.departureArrivalIATAString
        cell.depStopLabel.text = depTrip.stopsString
        cell.depDurationLabel.text = depTrip.getDurationString()

        if self.searchParameters.tripType == .ROUND_TRIP {
            let arrTrip = itinerary.getTrips()[1]

            cell.arrOtaLogo.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: (arrTrip.carrierMediumLogo)), placeholderImage: nil)
            cell.arrTimeLabel.text = arrTrip.getDepartureArrivalTime()
            cell.arrDelay.text = arrTrip.getDelayString()
            cell.arrIataLabel.text = arrTrip.departureArrivalIATAString
            cell.arrStopLabel.text = arrTrip.stopsString
            cell.arrDurationLabel.text = arrTrip.getDurationString()
        }

        cell.priceButton.tag = indexPath.row
        let buttonTitle = (indexPath.section == self.bookmarksIndex && !self.founded) ? "" : itinerary.getOffers()[0].price + self.offlineSymbol
        cell.priceButton.setTitle(buttonTitle, for: .normal)
        cell.priceButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        if self.searchParameters.isOfflineSelected() {
            cell.priceButton.isEnabled = false
         } else {
            cell.priceButton.isEnabled = true
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

I tried to reproduce this kind of crash with no luck.

Comment: The place where you construct the identifier on the fly and force cast the result would be a good place to poke around. Is there anyway to get an invalid value there?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately thet can’t, they are not optional strings and they got default value.

Comment: Can you reproduce if you start fresh (that is, do not currently have any images or data cached locally), and you scroll the table immediately after it appears? I suspect it may be a case of your cell being dequeued before all of the async operations have completed.

Comment: I tried and nothing happens. The only thing I got is that if I would try to scroll as faster as I can (non-human behaviour) the app will crash on NSURLSession, maybe because it's trying to fetch cell logo. But this is a EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS on libojbc.dylib (I can see only one report and it's about my crash). The problem about EXC_BREAKPOINT should be elsewhere somewhere. I could try a refactor in order to reduce non-deterministic behaviour due to the async operations, but It would be a blind attempt, and there's not so much to optimise.

Comment: I seem to have a crash very similar but with a collectionView. Did you find any solution ?

Comment: I am facing a similar crash too. Common thing is I am also doing an async operation in dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:) method.

Comment: What line does Crashlytics mark as crashed in your log? In my case it points at the  dequeueing with forced cast to cell type (identifier registered in storyboard and cell type is correct). I also have async `sd_setImage`, but in nested collection view's cell.